# Show that the subsets of the plane are open

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know that this set is open but I just don't know how to prove it. 
$A = \{(x,y) | -1< x <1, -1< y <1\}$

I looked at all the problems in my book but it only had problems like $B = \{(x,y)|y>0\}$ that involves only one variable?

Comment: What method did you use to show that $B = \{(x,y)|y > 0\}$ is open? Also, what is your book's definition of an open set?

Comment: the book says "take 0<r<=y, then for all points (x,y), the open disk Dr(x,y) is a set in B. thus, B is open"
im not sure if I understand what it means though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,y)\in A$. Then let $d=\text{min}\{1-x, x+1, 1-y, y+1\}$.

The shortest distance from a point in $A$ to the boundary of $A$ will be one of the orthogonal projections from the point onto the lines $x=\pm 1, y=\pm 1$. So the distance from $(x,y)$ to the boundary of $A$ is $d$. (Why?)

So $B_d((x,y)) \subset A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write down the basis for product topology on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

In general, a basic open set for product space $X\times Y$ is of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$.